# Is there any idiom or expression for someone who gets something without any effort?

Tags: idioms

Is there any idiom or expression for someone who gets something without any effort?
like a guy got a job without doing anything.. I want a idiom by which i can mock him.

Comment: Although it doesn't describe the person, you can say "It fell into his/her lap".

Comment: I've answered, but I think there are other interpretations of your quesiton. Do you mean for instance someone who is priviledged or accumulates wealth easily? It would help if you added some context.

Comment: I read this question interpreting “gets” as “comprehends.”  I’m thinking now that’s not what the OP meant.

Answer (score 1):

There's the idiom [**lucky duck or lucky ducky**](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/you+lucky+duck). From the free dictionary:

> lucky duck An incredibly lucky person; one who falls into good
>   fortune.
>  A: "I won another bet in the basketball
>   tournament—that's three in a row now!" 
> *B: "Wow, you lucky
>   duck!"* 
> Just when he was looking to take some time away from work
>   to focus on raising his kids, the company began offering really
>   excellent voluntary severance packages to reduce the number of staff.
>   *What a lucky duck, huh?*

I'd use this without thinking so was surprised that it has also taken on [another meaning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucky_duckies) to refer to American's who pay no income tax.

If you want something more formal or literary I'd suggest ***child of good fortune***.

There are plenty of references in Google books from the end of 18th century to the present day. eg. Jane Austen's Emma in 1816

> Those were Miss Woodhouse's words, were they? And a fine ending—and
>   there is the letter. 'The child of good fortune!' That was your name
>   for him, was it?” “You do not appear so well satisfied with his letter
>   [305] ...

and an edition of Grimm's fairytales in 1997

> And the Queen, when she had received the letter and read it, did as
>   was written in it, and had a splendid wedding-feast prepared, and the
>   King's daughter was married to the child of good fortune; and as the
>   youth was handsome and friendly ...

Similar in meaning:  ***fortune's darling*** or being ***born under a lucky star***.

Answer (score 0):

[fortune smiles on sb](https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/fortune-smiles-on-sb)

> If fortune smiles on you, you are lucky and good things happen to you.

Answer (score 0):

From dictionary.com: https://www.dictionary.com/browse/quick-study

**quick study**

> someone who is able to learn a new job or adjust to a new social environment in a short time.
>
> an actor who can learn lines and become proficient in a role on short notice.