# Is there any idiom or expression for someone who gets something without any kind of effort?

Tags: idioms

Is there any idiom or expression for someone who gets something without any effort? like a guy got a job without doing anything.. I want a idiom by which i can mock him

Comment: You asked [this question 2 days ago](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/508721/is-there-any-idiom-or-expression-for-someone-who-gets-something-without-any-effo) , and it was closed as a duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any idiom or expression for someone who gets something without any effort?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/508721/is-there-any-idiom-or-expression-for-someone-who-gets-something-without-any-effo)

Comment: Jammy ***** is what I'd suggest, but *Lucker* might be more appropriate (although I can only find it in the urban dictionary)

Comment: @Smock: We're a bit coarser in my neck of the woods, so it's "jammy ****". Why use a five-character euphemism where the context justifies a full-blown four-letter-word? :)

Comment: As a white guy in the US, I'm highly **entitled**. -Not sure this made it into many of the near duplicates.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Ha! Yeah I probably would use a 4 letter one when speaking. The word I was thinking of actually had 7 letters, not sure why I put 5.

Comment: @Smock: It's primarily a football-related term today (applied to an exceptionally *talented* player), but back when I was a kid, we commonly used the label [***Goldenballs***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22the+British+would+say+goldenballs%22) for anyone who often seemed unusually and/or unfairly ***lucky*** (or sometimes, ***privileged***).

Comment: We used to call people who always seemed to have good fortune a *Jamster* when we were kids. (Like a *trickster* [-ster](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/-ster)). We then morphed it for someone lucky at sport into a *Jamstar* (*Jammy* + *star*).