# Idiomatic word or expression for a lazy and unmoral person who gets paid without working - Translation of Spanish ‘ñoqui’

Tags: single-word-requests, idioms, translation, spanish

I'm not talking about the Italian dish. In Argentina, there's a well known expression for someone who doesn't go to work and only assists the last month's day to get paid: It's called a *ñoqui*. The origin for this meaning of the word is not clear, but most people believe is due to the fact that, historically, the public employees got the salary on the same day the tradition dictates eating gnocchis: on 29th day of every month. That would be the supposed origin for this new meaning.

I found some similar questions like [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/508721/is-there-any-idiom-or-expression-for-someone-who-gets-something-without-any-effo). But that does not leave me satisfied. The meaning to convey is not about someone who is skilled and can accomplish every goal they have doing little effort. Instead, I wan't to say something like:

> ‘They are immoral, and don't do everything they are supposed to do in order to fulfill the conditions under which they were contracted. However, they get paid.’

That would be the definition. You could suppose they might be a friend of their boss, or the boss can be easily deluded, etc. That doesn't matter now.

What is this person? Is there a simple idiomatic word (expression if not possible) that capture the quiddity of these people, like in Spanish? What would you say?

P. S. The example:

> Fui a hacer un trámite al Ministerio y el tipo que me atendió me tuvo esperando media hora y cuando me da los papeles los había hecho mal. Un incompetente total. Debe ser alto **ñoqui**.

> I went to the Ministry to do a procedure and the guy that attended me got me waiting half an hour and when he gave me the documents he realized that he made mistakes. A completely incompetent. He must be a **???**.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What do you call a person that only do the minimum to get through day-to-day basis?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/165550/191178)

Comment: Do you mean _assist_ in the sense _be present_? It doesn't have that meaning in English. (I'm guessing that you do because it is also a 'false friend' in French.)

Comment: The question linked above has a lot of examples, and you can check out a thesaurus for moocher, freeloader, Bartleby, and other terms. Otherwise you'll have to be more precise: if someone is the friend of the boss that's a different situation to if they are skilled at doing nothing and covering up their idleness, or if they can't be fired for institutional reasons (e.g. union rules), or if they're employed for one reason but are otherwise shit, or if they don't try at all but the situation allows them to be lazy and incompetent with no consequences.

Comment: Yes, that answered my question. thanks a lot

Comment: Funny how nobody ever shows up here asking for our help in saying something ***nice*** about somebody else. Instead it's always about saying horrible things about something we disapprove of, even though this has never required fancy words to sting the worst.